# Deploying a newly developed Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have written an Eclpise plugin (an Error Parser for the CDT), and it works just fine in the debugger version of eclipse.  However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install the plugin into eclipse.  I can export the plugin as a jar file, and it seems to export without errors.  I put the plugin jar file into eclipse\dropins and it is not loaded by eclipse.  If I add it to the plugins directory, no luck.  The features directory also seems to ignore my plugin.

So I thought, OK, I'll try installing it through the GUI.  So I browse to where the plugin archive is and add it as a local update site, but eclipse complains there is no plugin there.

I'm frustrated.  Please help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Putting the plugin into the eclipse/plugins folder should work. If it doesn't, that usually means Eclipse has cached the plugins configuration for performance reasons. You can force Eclipse to rescan the plugins directory for changes by starting it with the **-clean** command-line argument.

The typical deployment mechanism for Eclipse is to use features. A feature includes plugins (in your case, probably just one), and can be installed through the Eclipse update manager. To deploy your plugin using a feature, you would do the following:

1. Create a feature project, and add your plugin to the feature using the feature editor.
2. Create an update site project, and add your feature to the update site, using the update site editor.
3. Build the update site. This creates a site.xml file, a features folder, and a plugins folder.

You should then be able to point the Eclipse update manager at the folder or URL containing the site.xml, and install your plugin that way. The advantage of this approach is you can upload the files to a website and deploy remotely.

Comment: Jordan is it possible to force Eclipse to rescan the dropins folder without restarting Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

No Idea What I did to screw up my eclipse install.  But reinstalling eclipse and putting the plugin in dropins worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

there is a folder under the directory C:\eclipse\plugin just copy that .jar file and paste it into this folder before doing this close the eclipse IDE and open it again when u are done check the plugin effect

Answer (score 1):

Here is more information:
To use your plug-ins in your standard Eclipse installation you can either export it locally as plug-in and place it into your Eclipse installation or you export it as feature and use the Eclipse update manager to install it....
http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#deployplugin

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my plugin was not being loaded was that my plugin had features of CDT and CDT Development SDK was not installed in eclipse.

Once I installed the CDT Development SDK tools, my plugin was loaded automatically.