# Import Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, export

I developed an Eclipse plugin (a view) using the plugin development version of Eclipse. I exported the plugin as a jar archive and now I would like import it in another version of Eclipse, but it doesn't recognize the plugin.

This is my first plugin so I might have forgotten something obvious. I searched the internet for hours but didn't find anything. Does anybody know what else I have to do?

Btw, the dependencies of my plugin are:
org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem,
 edu.tum.cs.eclipse.commons,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.core.resources

The version I'd like to import it in is the default Eclipse for PHP Developers from eclipse.org. The feature list can be found on http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/galileosr2

Thanks for you help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying a newly developed Eclipse Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266935/deploying-a-newly-developed-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 minutes after asking the question, I solved the problem...

Setting up an update site as suggested here at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266935/deploying-a-newly-developed-eclipse-plugin) provided the proper errors and I could set up the plugin.